# What type of methylcellulose would be appropriate as binding agent for insect based noodles?

Tags: substitutions, pasta

I’m trying to make spaghetti out of insect flour(50% insect flour and 50% durum wheat flour) for my university project. I need a binding agent (gluten alternative) for this, and I thought about methylcellulose, except I’m not sure which type of methylcellulose and the proportions to use. Do you have any directions to help me?

Comment: Methylcellulose is more commonly used as a bulking agent.  Maybe you mean transglutaminase?  Are you using water or egg?  Have you tried it with no additional ingredients (just the insect flour, durum flour and liquid)? What were the results?

Comment: Just with the insect flour, wheat, and water, the pasta falling apart. I tried transglutaminase at different doses but did not get a sufficiently stable texture. So I intend to combine transglutaminase and methylcellulose to improve the texture of the noodles.

Comment: Have you considered the addition of vital wheat gluten?  ...just a thought...oh, and there are different formulations of transglutaminase for different systems.

Comment: I wouldn't expect good results from TG... the protein in insect flour is cooked, lowering the potential bonding quality.

Comment: could you explain why cooking would reduce the potential bonding quality? It might be useful for my work.